# Need help with HTML footer code for modern sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, html, footer

I have a requirement in modern SharePoint to achieve footer as shown in screenshot below, I am using an SPFX web part through a github solution to embed footer and header in a modern sharepoint page and the web part is deployed to the tenant and its working great.

I Just need to embed the html in the web part so need help on html code for achieving below.
[image]

Can someone please help me with the HTML snippet, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have bootstrapped the footer solution. In the solution just paste your HTML code on `spfxFooter/src/extensions/footer/Footer.tsx` file from line number 6. Keep in mind that `render()` method must return a single root node.

Comment: https://github.com/thinkb4code/spfxFooter

Comment: I am not looking for spfx solution,i already have that setup, just need html code to render footer.

Comment: do you know how to work with HTML & CSS?